# Java Jtextpane produce OutOfMemoryError error

Tags: java, macos, out-of-memory, jscrollpane

I'm creating a text editor in java whith a JtextPane component and i have a problem on MAC OS.
The JTextPane is added in a JScrollPane, which is added into a JFrame.
My document is very long and the textpane can reach more than 10000 px high, and produce this exception :

```
**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: can't create offscreen surface**
   at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLSurfaceData.initSurfaceNow(OGLSurfaceData.java:298)
   at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLSurfaceData.access$000(OGLSurfaceData.java:98)
   at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLSurfaceData$1.run(OGLSurfaceData.java:324)
   at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLRenderQueue$QueueFlusher.run(OGLRenderQueue.java:234)
```

I work on MAC OS 10.8, under Java 7u60.

My researche shows that a protection was added under MAC OS Jre and throws OutOfMemoryError when components are to big.
(https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=215397 or https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8040617).

Do you know a solution to solve the problem ? (I must display the totality of my form, like in word).

Comment: I think your assumptions may be incorrect: `"I must display the totality of my form, like in word"` -- Word does **not** hold the totality of the document in memory, but rather caches portions of the document to disk if the document is very large and pulls the data from cache when needed. It only appears to display the whole document, and you'll probably need to do the same thing.

Comment: The term you want to look up is "pagination"

Comment: Ok. So if i don't have choice, i'll try to use pagination under my JTextPane.

Comment: Assuming of course that you've first used command line parameters to give Java as much memory memory as possible.

Comment: Ok thanks for help. I will try to use pagination if there is no other solution.

Comment: The problem is not the memory allocated to te JRE. Yes i use the -Xmx command.
Yhe problem is the jre under MAC OS which seems to not allow big components.